# Libgdx for android shows black before main screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am making a game in LibGDX, and I have noticed that when my game is launched a black screen is shown for a few moments before the white screen of my game is drawn.

I have set the background of my app's theme to be a different color with `android:windowBackground` in my app's **style.xml**, and the preview window shows that color.   However, right before the main screen of my app loads, the screen goes black for a moment before displaying the main screen.

I've tried setting `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1)` in the main activity and Game class of my game, but the black screen still shows for a moment before drawing the main screen.

The only way I've found to fix this is to set the `android:windowDisablePreview` to true, but that disables the preview window all together.

Is there any way to fix this without disabling the preview?

Comment: Are you loading all the assets and creating the objects immediately once your app is launched?

Comment: @SteveL I am loading the assets and creating objects in the `show()` method of my class that extends Screen.  I tried moving the object creation into the constructor of my class, but that didn't help.  The black screen is inconsistent, but that is most likely caused by available memory.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to shifting objects creation to constructor, you also need to shift the ApplicationListener object creation in Activity class's constructor.
The black screen is probably because of the time delay between start of Activity.onCreate() call and end of ApplicationListener.show() call.
Try to measure it using a timer or simply System.currentTimeMillis() so the difference would be visible.
This should improve the situation if not eliminate the problem.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I can't start loading textures until after the application is initialized.  It takes about 800ms between the end of the Activity.onCreate() and the end of ApplicationListener.create() method.  If I remove the texture and screen loading, that loading time cuts in half, and the black screen goes away.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes. There is a standard way. Texture loading should not be in create method. You should have a standalone loading screen with progress bar (to which gamers don't complain :D ). Only the textures required to draw loading screen should be loaded at start. So black screen wouldn't be an issue. Good luck.